# Access of undefined propety and other errors (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

ok so I am trying to work on making my scripts external .as files.
I had them on the timeline and they worked fine but when I put them in the as file they don't work at all.
This is my code as of right now

so I got the script working externally thank you very much :)
I just need to addchild to the stage. I use

```
import Scripts.resources.main;

var Main:main = new main;

addChild(Main);
```

In my external script I addchild in the main function now.

```
package Scripts.resources
{
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLVariables;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequestMethod;
import flash.events.OutputProgressEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.EventDispatcher;


public class main extends EventDispatcher{

    private var _stage:Stage;
    var url:String = "php/data_user.php";
    //declare our graphic vars
    var stmBar:resourceBar;
    var tenBar:resourceBar;
    var potBar:resourceBar;
    var spdBar:resourceBar;
    var crtBar:resourceBar;
    var awrBar:resourceBar;
    var resBar:resourceBar;
    var statUp:Sprite;

    //This Returns the number of milliseconds since midnight January 1, 1970
    //Tacking the time variable at the end of your php file locations will ensure their is no caching
    var now:Date = new Date();
    var time:Number = now.getTime();

    /*
    *  These should point to your PHP files. I recommend NOT using an http path because accessing
    *  the site via 'www.yoursite.com' versus 'yoursite.com' makes a difference and will cause undefined
    *  issues. Instead use a relative path like: var registerLocation:String = "membership/php/register.php";
    */

    var registerLocation:String = "php/register.php" + "?" + time;
    var loginLocation:String = "php/login.php" + "?" + time;
    var editProfileLocation:String = "php/editprofile.php" + "?" + time;
    var forgotPWLocation:String = "php/forgotpw.php" + "?" + time;
    var statsLocation:String = "php/user_stats.php" + "?" + time;
    var statsGylph:String = "php/data_user.php" + "?" + time;

    //userInfo is the Object that gets populated that stores all of the users information.
    var userInfo:Object = new Object();

    //The minimum length of a password.
    var passwordLength:Number = 4;

    /*
    *  var cookie refers to swfObjects addVariable. If you look at membership.php, where swf
    *  object is defined, addVariable shows a var called usercookie.
    *  This help decide if the program should remember the users username or not.
    */
    //cookieUserName would be the username that gets put into the user field if the cookie has been set

public function main(stage:Stage)
{
        _stage = stage;
        var _loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
        var _request:URLRequest = new URLRequest(url + "?id=" + userInfo.id);
        _request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
        _loader.load(_request);
        _stage.addChild(stmBar);
        stmBar.x = -50;
        stmBar.y = 200;
    }
     public function MyClass(){
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);


    }

    private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);

        //this code will run after you've added this object to the stage
        //it is the equivalent of when timeline code runs
    }
        function onLoadData(e:Event):void {
            var str:String =  e.target.data;

            var array:Array =str.split("-");
            for(var i:int;i < array.length; i++)
               output(i+1,array[i]);
        }

     public function output(field:Number,i:int):void 
        {
            if (field == 5)
            {
            stmBar = new resourceBar(0, 0, i, "Stamina", 0x990000);
            stmBar.x = -200;
            stmBar.y = 50;
            }
            else if (field == 6)
            {
            tenBar = new resourceBar(0, 0, i, "Tenacity", 0xFF9900);
            tenBar.x = 200;
            tenBar.y = 50;
            }
            else if (field == 7)
            {
            potBar = new resourceBar(0, 0, i, "Potency", 0xCC3399);
            potBar.x = -200;
            potBar.y = 100;
            }
            else if (field == 8)
            {
            spdBar = new resourceBar(0, 0, i, "Speed", 0x00CC00);
            spdBar.x = 200;
            spdBar.y = 100;
            }
            else if (field == 9)
            {
            crtBar = new resourceBar(0, 0, i, "Crit", 0x009999);
            crtBar.x = -200;
            crtBar.y = 150;
            }
            else if (field == 10)
            {
            awrBar = new resourceBar(0, 0, i, "Awareness", 0x3399CC);
            awrBar.x = 200;
            awrBar.y = 150;
            }
            else if (field == 11)
            {
            resBar = new resourceBar(0, 0, i, "Resistance", 0x999999);
            resBar.x = -200;
            resBar.y = 200;

            addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onLoop);
            }
        function onLoop(e:Event):void
        {       
            stmBar.change(1);
            tenBar.change(1);
            potBar.change(1);
            spdBar.change(1);
            crtBar.change(1);
            awrBar.change(1);
            resBar.change(1);
        }
    }
}

}
```

my problem is it won't add the children in the main function when I addchild of main. am I able to add a child with children inside it?

Comment: First,  main is NOT a display object (you're extending `EventDispatcher`), so it can't be added to the display (this should be throwing an error).   Second, you are not passing in a reference to the `stage` when you instantiate `main`,   so the `stage` var will be null - this should also be throwing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In class files, all code needs to be wrapped in a function.  So where you have:

```
        _loader = new URLLoader();
        _request = new URLRequest(url + "?id=" + (STAGE.parent as MovieClip).userInfo.id);
        _request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
        _loader.load(_request);
```

You need to place it in a function for the code to be valid. If you want that bit of code to run right away, then you can place it in a constructor (that is the function in class that runs when you instantiate with the `new` keyword, eg `new main()`.  If `main` is your document class, then the constructor is the very first code to run in the application.

Constructors are `public` functions that have the exact name of your `Class`.

```
    public function main(){
        _loader = new URLLoader();
        _request = new URLRequest(url + "?id=" + (STAGE.parent as MovieClip).userInfo.id);
        _request.method = URLRequestMethod.GET;
        _loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoadData);
        _loader.load(_request);
    }
```

Something to keep in mind, is that in the constructor of display objects, the `stage/parent/root` keywords will NOT have any value,  as those are populated once the display object has been added to the display.  So, it's common to use this approach:

```
package MyClass extends Sprite {
    public function MyClass(){
        this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);
    }

    private function addedToStage(e:Event):void {
        this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStage);

        //this code will run after you've added this object to the stage
        //it is the equivalent of when timeline code runs
    }
}
```

Also, a tip now that you are writing class files - follow the convention of making class names start with an Uppercase letter, and instances of classes start with lowercase letters.

Comment: is it possible to add the one of the resourcebars with addchild to the stage when I add the main function aschild? so say I want to add stmBar how would I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand?  It looks you are already adding `stmBar` in your `output` function.

Comment: I updated my original post. with info of what my problem is. I am trying to addchild of main on the timeline to add the children within it. but its not putting anything on the stage. I also get no errors